# The type: Byte cannot be coerced effectively to a GraphQL type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, graphql-dotnet

Here is the code that I am using to fetch ByteArrayContent type:

```
public class ImageDTO : APIResult
{
    public byte[] ImageData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ImageFormat
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ImageDTO()
    {
        ImageData = new byte[]{};
    }
}

public class ImageType : ObjectGraphType<ImageDTO>, IGraphQLType
{
    public ImageType()
    {
        Field(img => img.ImageData);
        Field(img => img.ImageFormat);
    }
}

public class ImageResolver : Resolver, IImageResolver
{
    private readonly ICommonService _commonService;
    public ImageResolver(ICommonService commonService)
    {
        _commonService = commonService;
    }

    public void Resolve(GraphQLQuery graphQLQuery)
    {
        graphQLQuery.Field<ResponseGraphType<ImageType>>("imageresponse", arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>{Name = "imageId", Description = "id of the project"}), resolve: context =>
        {
            var imageId = context.GetArgument<string>("imageId");
            var imageResult = _commonService.GetImage(imageId);
            if (imageResult == null)
            {
                return NotFoundError(imageId);
            }

            return Response(imageResult);
        }

        );
    }
}
```

On executing the above code I am getting the below mentioned error.
The type: Byte cannot be coerced effectively to a GraphQL type\r\nParameter name: type\r\n at Type GraphQL.

From the link :  https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/458 , it is mentioned that ByteGraphType is supported. I am using GraphQL.net nuget package with version:2.3.0 . So I believe it should support the ByteGraphType.

Can you please help me here to know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this line => `Field(img => img.ImageData);`

you can use this => `Field(img  => img.ImageData, type: typeof(IdGraphType));`